# C# - NPOI library: Edit template file(xlsx) containing shape group corrupts the file output

Tags: c#, npoi

I have a question with npoi library and hope to get your helps.

When editing from template file contains **simple shape group** to create new file, after opening new file and i get the following error message:

```
Removed Part: /xl/drawings/drawing1.xml part.  (Drawing shape)
```

I want to emphasize in template file only contains simple shape group.

Here's the template file, [here](https://ufile.io/lcvon).

Here's code test.

```
XSSFWorkbook wb1 = null;
using (var file = new FileStream("E:\\template.xlsx", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
        wb1 = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
}

using (var file2 = new FileStream("E:\\output.xlsx", FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
{
        wb1.Write(file2);
        file2.Close();
}
```

Version NPOI 2.2.1 https://npoi.codeplex.com/releases

Sorry for my English is not good.

Comment: I have the same problem!